# Electron / Nativefier Web App - new window print problem [HTML, JS]

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-applications, electron

I have constructed an desktop app with [Nativefier](https://github.com/jiahaog/Nativefier) witch is based on [Eelectron JS](https://www.electronjs.org/).
I come across problem with printing, a problem manifests only when trying to open a new window with preview for print.

I have a lot of tables and every one of them has this code attached to make them printable (with slight differences):

```
    function printData3()
{
   var divToPrint=document.getElementById("myTable");
    var htmlToPrint = '' +
        '<style type="text/css">' +
        'table th, table td {' +
        'border:1px solid #000;' +
        'padding:0.5em;' +
        '}' +
        '</style>';
    htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
    newWin = window.open("");
    newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.print(htmlToPrint);
    newWin.close();
}

$(document.getElementById("print-pred")).on('click',function(){
printData3();
})
```

This works fine on all browsers in normal conditions but in app it fails with error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'write' of undefined
    at printData3 (rad.php:1373)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (rad.php:1379)
    at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2)
    at HTMLButtonElement.v.handle (jquery.min.js:2)
```

And that error line refers to: `newWin.document.write(htmlToPrint);` from code shown above.

This code however works fine and starts a print dialog right away:

```
function myFunction() {
  window.print();
```

Witch led me to believe (it's a guess, correct if I am wrong) problem is in opening a new window with print preview as Web App itself is Chromeless and design to work in one window only.

Now as mentioned before I have this code implemented in little less then 100 instances with some variations so it would be big problem for me to change it all together on all locations.

So my question is can the first code shown above be somehow minimally altered to jump to print dialog first (skipping the new window preview part)? So I can do simple  search/replace all files.

**EDIT:**
**Solution posted as answer.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution.

```
htmlToPrint += divToPrint.outerHTML;
newWin = window.document.write(htmlToPrint);
window.print();
location.reload();
```

I don't open a new window. In current I open a document and write table in it, bring up a window print dialog and save as PDF or print it. After I close it the location reloads and closes new document by itself and returns on table page.

Works in browser and App.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very familiar with "Nativefier" but I guess `newWin` variable has no property like "document", error is saying that.
But with Electron, you can use `webContents` method - `executeJavascript`:

```
// Warning: pure Electron, no add-ons or something like Nativefier
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

app.once('ready', () => {
  var mainWindow = new BrowserWindow()
  mainWindow.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'))
  mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
    document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += '<h1>Hey Wassup</h1>'
  `)
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Well I'm no expert in JS so that information is not worth much to me unfortunately.

Comment: check the answer again, maybe only-electron solution may help you, @ikiK

Comment: Thanks, but made it work without Electron, see my answer. Thank you tho anyway.